# IIS 8.5 - 301 redirect and ampersand

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am struggling get 301 redirects to work when the url includes an ampersand in iis. The code I am using is below :

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect rule1 for 301-maps">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{301-maps:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>        

        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="301-maps">
            <add key="/mobile/product.htm?id=139" value="/" /> << works
            <add key="/mobile/product.htm?id=139&subid=1" value="/" /> << fails syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All what you need, is to use `&amp;` in place of `&`. Your url in rewrite map should be:

```
<add key="/mobile/product.htm?id=139&amp;subid=1" value="/" />
```

In XML you need to escape this 5 symbols:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

Comment: Darn, thought I tried this but must not have; solution works.